# How to add section headers / footers to a UICollectionView that uses UICollectionViewFlowLayout and UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource, uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout

I went through a lot of articles and documentation. Everywhere `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` is used alongside `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource`.

`supplementaryViewProvider` is used to dequeue the supplementary view. But how to get it invoked while the layout is `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add **boundarySupplementaryItems** while configuring your **NSCollectionLayoutSection**. Something like:

```
let headerSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
    widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
    heightDimension: YOUR_HEIGHT
)
let headerItem = NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem(
    layoutSize: headerSize,
    elementKind: YOUR_HEADER_IDENTIFIER,
    alignment: .top
)
sectionItem.boundarySupplementaryItems = [headerItem]
```